# how to create unique constraints on multiple columns with one column can have single null value

Tags: postgresql, database-design

How to create unique constraints on multiple columns with one column can have single null value
I need unique constraints on col3 col4 col4 , where col4 can have one null value

Example :

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col4
1      A1   S1    V1     P1 
2      A1  S1     V1     null
```

It should not allow following entries

```
3     A1  S1    V1   null   
3     A1  S1    V1   P1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_TABLE_NAME_UC 
   ON TABLE_NAME (col2, col3, coalesce(col4,'null')) ;
```